# Orthorectification errors in ArcMap when including RPC data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, photogrammetry, orthorectification

I am trying to orthorectify satellite imagery with a DEM in ArcMap. I have already georeferenced the raster.

The imagery came with an RPC TXT file, but when I change the name of the RPC file to match the new, georeferenced raster image (by adding a "1"), the tile is completely shifted and partly clipped when I use the "Create Ortho Corrected Raster Dataset" tool.

```
Original file name: *******0004.tif
New file name:      *******00041.tif (I added the "1" to RPC file to match this).
```

Do I have bad RPC data?

Comment: I suggest changing the title of your question

Comment: If I understand correctly, an RPC file contains some georeferencing information. Did you georeference to TIFF to the same coordinate reference system that the RPC is referring to?

Comment: To my knowledge the RPC file contains an abstract of the sensor/camera math. I did not see any evidence of a georeference in the file. The imagery was left in its native Datum, WGS84.

Comment: RPC is something new to me but this might be worth reading http://geotiff.maptools.org/rpc_prop.html.

Comment: If you manually georectified a raster you invalidated the RPC. The RPC *is* the full ortho details.

Comment: The ortho tool does work with the original imagery. I will apply the orthorectification first and manually georeference second, as the imagery still doesn't match the basemap. Thank you for all of your help!